# how to get folder name in this

Tags: php, jquery

hello every ine in this i get file name and i crate hyperlink on it but foldername is missing to further action my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var files=<?php echo json_encode($files);?>;
var file_tree=build_file_tree(files);
file_tree.appendTo('#files');

function build_file_tree(files){
    var tree=$('<ul>');
    for(x in files){

        if(typeof files[x]=="object"){
        var span=$('<span>').html(x).appendTo(
        $('<li>').appendTo(tree).addClass('folder')
        );

        var subtree=build_file_tree(files[x]).hide();
        span.after(subtree);
        span.click(function(){

        $(this).parent().find('ul:first').toggle();
    });

    }else{
    $('<li>').html('<a href="/admin/appearance/?theme='+tree+'&file='+files[x]+'">'+files[x]+'</a>').appendTo(tree).addClass('file');
      }
    }

    return tree;

}

} );

</script>
```

i want folder name after theme=

Comment: which framework you using?

Comment: `tree` is a jQuery object, it can't be concantenated into a string ?

Comment: I see this javascript file tree code in quite a few places. I'm using it too. One guy keeps posting "I wrote this code" when he didn't he just copied it. I wish when people post code they copy & paste from original sources, that they would give attribution to the original author. Actually, I'm trying to find the original page where this code was copied from. If anybody can point me to it, it would be appreciated. If you post the original source it goes a long way toward helping with your specific application of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `tree` is a jQuery DOM object returned from `$('<ul>')` and you can't concatenate it into a string. I would guess you're trying to get innerHTML or text of the parent element. Consider the following HTML:

```html
<ul id="upper"> <!-- `tree` you're talking about -->
  <li class="folder">folder-name</li>
    <ul id="here">  <!-- `tree` you're talking about -->
      <li>file-name-1</li>
      <li>file-name-2</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Let's say your loop is now at `#here`. Your folder name is likely to be returned from the `<li class="folder">` of the parent `<ul id="upper">`;

```
var tree = $('#here');
alert(tree.parent().find('.folder').text());
```

So, you may be able to replace `theme='+tree+'&` with `theme=' + tree.parent().find('.folder').text() + '&`. However, you should set `id` and `class` appropriately to traverse your DOM tree correctly. Then, you have to use the right class/id to get the folder name by a correct DOM traversing.

Your question is not clear. So my answer may not resolve it at once, but I hope you may get an idea from this.

### [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cithukyaw/29qz1568/)